# Not able to change the speed effect in Kdenlive

Tags: 17.10, kdenlive

I am trying to change the speed effect of a video in Kdenlive.
after clicking on speed effect it is not showing speed percentage.
I want to fast forward the video. So I want to change the speed percentage to 50% but it is not showing anything.

Comment: The is no speed effect under motion.

Comment: Yeah, this is about a very old version of Kdenlive, the solutions don't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your video timeline right click on the clip you want to change the speed of and select: add effect -> motion -> speed (this is deprecated, see Update below)

in the properties box you will see the speed effect listed with a slider and percent box

if you don't see the slider click on the arrow next to the word "Speed" to un-collapse the effect window

**Update**

In the latest version of KDEnlive right-click on the clip in the timeline and select the "Change Speed" option.